# SQL Timetable system

Tags: sql

So currently I have a scheduling system that displays results to the screen where open slots can be filled by the user. Below is a link to what it currently looks like.

[image]

The problem occurs when I want to start a new week.The table is made up of 63 slots. This is the current query that I am currently using:

```
Select  volunteer.F_Name
      , volunteer.L_Name
      , session.Session_Id
      , vol_session.Vol_Id
      , WEEK(vol_session.Date)
From    vol_session
Right Join session
        On vol_session.Session_ID = session.Session_Id
Left Join volunteer
        On volunteer.Vol_ID = vol_session.Vol_Id
Where   WEEK(vol_session.Date) Is Null
        Or WEEK(vol_session.Date) = '6'
Order By session.Session_Id;
```

What happens is if a volunteer picks the same slot on another week the query doesn't display all 63 results.

[image]

As you can see the result 18 is missing because someone in the next week has taken this slot. What needs to happen is that this missing 18 slot should show up NULL so that I am able to allow it to be booked.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN combined with LEFT JOIN... Just too confusing... (Switch to LEFT JOIN only, because `main table left join optional data` is much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.)

Comment: Your `RIGHT JOIN` is being negated by your `WEEK(vol_session.Date) = '6'` portion of the `WHERE` clause, forcing it to be an `INNER JOIN`.  Move that `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause.  Better yet, don't mix `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins in the same query.  Even better, don't use `RIGHT JOIN` at all.

Comment: @Siyual, there's a IS NULL or-ed. However, still a very good advice.

Comment: @jarlh Right, but the `Or WEEK(vol_session.Date) = '6'` should still filter records.

Comment: @Siyual After changing the query to LEFT joins only the query outputs only 3 results but I need all 63 to appear